# Network check before RxJava network call

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I need help with correctly using retrofit cache before making network call. If activity is launched without internet and cache is empty, I want to show network error always.

I have used RxJava to fetch data into my recyclerview and it works fine. I just need help with handling empty cache without network.

```
private void fetchData() {
            mUtils.getCachedLessons() //From cache
                        .doFinally(() -> {
                            mUtils.getLessons() // From Network
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .map(new Function<WeekResponse, List<WeekModel>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public List<WeekModel> apply(
                                            @io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull final WeekResponse response)
                                            throws Exception {
                                        return response.getResult();
                                    }

                                })
                                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<WeekModel>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(
                                            @io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull final List<WeekModel> dataList)
                                            throws Exception {

                                        mDataList.addAll(dataList);
                                        mWeekAdapter.set(mDataList);
                                    }

                                });
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .map(new Function<WeekResponse, List<WeekModel>>() {
                        @Override
                        public List<WeekModel> apply(
                                @io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull final WeekResponse response)
                                throws Exception {
                            return response.getResult();
                        }

                    })
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<List<WeekModel>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(
                                @io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull final List<WeekModel> dataList)
                                throws Exception {

                            mDataList.addAll(dataList);
                            mWeekAdapter.set(mDataList);
                        }

                    });


        }

    private boolean isConnected() {
            try {
                android.net.ConnectivityManager e = (android.net.ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(
                        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = e.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("TAG", e.toString());
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Is there a better way for me to this with RxJava to implement my need?

Comment: Can you post the code from getting a result from the cache?

Comment: What kind of observables `mUtils.getCachedLessons()` and `mUtils.getLessons()` return? What does `mUtils.getCachedLessons()` do when there is no available cache?